# How to populate lightning-datatable depending on which lightning button (with onclick handler) is clicked on?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-datatable

I created a LeadsContoller with multiple methods each returning a list of leads via a SOQL Query. I created multiple lightning buttons in HTML each with an onclick handler. In the JS file, i imported salesforce schema and the controller class methods. I can't get the datatable to populate any data when I click on them.

HTML: `

```
        <p class="slds-text-heading_medium">Select a status</p>

        <br>

        <div class="buttons">
            <lightning-button label="All" onclick={allLeadsHandler}></lightning-button>

            <lightning-button label="Open - Not Contacted" onclick={openNotContactedHandler}></lightning-button>

            <lightning-button label="Working Contacted" onclick={workingContactedHandler}></lightning-button>

            <lightning-button label="Closed - Converted" onclick={closedConvertedHandler}></lightning-button>

            <lightning-button label="Closed - Not Converted" onclick={closedNotConvertedHandler}></lightning-button>
        </div>
        
        <div class="table">
            <template if:true={leads.data}>
                <lightning-datatable data={data} columns={columns} key-field="id"></lightning-datatable>
            </template>
            <template if:true={error}>
                <lightning-datatable errors={error}></lightning-datatable>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</lightning-card>
```

`

CONTROLLER

```
public with sharing class LeadsController {
//get all leads method
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static List<Lead> getAllLeads(){
    return [
        SELECT Name, Company, Email, Phone, Status
        FROM Lead
        WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
        ORDER BY Name
    ];
}
//get open - not contacted leads method
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Lead> getOpenNotContactedLeads(){
    return [
        SELECT Name, Company, Email, Phone, Status
        FROM Lead
        WHERE Status = 'Open - Not Contacted'
        WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
        ORDER BY Name
    ];
}
```

The rest of the controller file is the same. I'm just saving room.

JS:

```
    import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';

//import schema fields
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Name';
import COMPANY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Company';
import EMAIL_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Email';
import PHONE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Phone';
import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Status';
//import controller methods
import getAllLeads from '@salesforce/apex/LeadsController.getAllLeads';
import getOpenNotContactedLeads from '@salesforce/apex/LeadsController.getOpenNotContactedLeads';
import getWorkingContactedLeads from '@salesforce/apex/LeadsController.getWorkingContactedLeads';
import getClosedConvertedLeads from '@salesforce/apex/LeadsController.getClosedConvertedLeads';
import getClosedNotConvertedLeads from '@salesforce/apex/LeadsController.getClosedNotConvertedLeads';

const COLUMNS = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'text'},
    { label: 'Company', fieldName: COMPANY_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'text'},
    { label: 'Email', fieldName: EMAIL_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'email'},
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: PHONE_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'phone'},
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: STATUS_FIELD.fieldApiName, type: 'text'},
];

export default class LeadsFilter extends LightningElement {
    @track error;
    @track leads;
    columns = COLUMNS;
    
     
    //  @wire(getAllLeads)
    //     wiredLeads({error, data}) {
    //         if(data) {
    //             this.leads = data;
    //         } else if (error) {
    //             console.log(error);
    //             this.error = error;
    //         }
    //     }
    allLeadsHandler(){
        getAllLeads()
            .then(data => {
                this.leads = data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            })
       
    }

    openNotContactedHandler(){
        getOpenNotContactedLeads()
            .then(data => {
                this.leads = data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            })
    }
```

rest of the JS file is the same for each button onclick handler.

I've tried several different approaches but what I have in the JS file is based on examples i've seen a few different sites. Nothing happens when I click on the buttons except.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of suggestions:

you don't need 2 apex methods, you can use 1 with a property that determins if the where clause is needed or not, for ex (this is just for reference purposes):

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
public static List<Lead> getAllLeads(Some Property){
    String query = 'some soql';
    if(String.isNotBlank(Property)){
        queryString += 'WHERE Status = \'Open - Not Contacted\''
    }
    return Database.query(queryString);
}
```

that way, in your lwc controller you can simply toggle a property to fetch your soql with the applied status or not.

you could use a dynamic property in your wiremethod, so each time that you toggle the status proeprty, the aura method would be invoked.

`@wire(getAllLeads, Property : '$yourProperty')`

Comment: I actually have 5 methods querying different statuses. I get the idea behind using @wire. Since I can only apply it to one method, how can I place all those in one apex method?  The html has 5 buttons. Depending on which button is clicked, an onclick handler is used to populate lead object data for teh various status options.

Comment: based on what I shared you should be able to develop your own functionality without having 5 wire methods and 5 apex classes to handle separate/different queries for the same object. Please keep in mind that this site is not a free coding service.